# How do I find a sentence segment between punctuation marks that contains a specific search term

Tags: python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I need to do some natural language processing that requires me to find all sentence segments that contain a certain search term. To do this, I want to get all the words between any punctuation marks that contain the search term. For example, I can easily get the words before and after the search term using the code below. I could also write more complicated logic that break it down, but I am trying to figure out if I can do this using one line of regex.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of regex lookahead and lookbehind patterns with various results but none of them achieve the results I'm seeking. I can get everything between two of the same punctuation marks, e.g. everything between two periods (i.e. starlist = re.findall(r'([^.]*?Star Trek[^.]*.)',s) The problem seems to be when I try to use groups, e.g. [.;:,]? Anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
s = 'Star Trek is an American media franchise, based on the science fiction television series; created by Star Trek legend Gene Roddenberry. The first television series, simply called Star Trek, and now referred to as "The Original Series", debuted in 1966 and aired for three seasons on NBC. It followed the Star Trek adventures of Captain James T. Kirk (William Shatner), and his crew aboard the starship USS Enterprise, a star exploration vessel built by the United Federation of Planets in the 23rd century. The Star Trek canon includes The Original Series: five Star Trek spin-off television series; an animated series; the Star Trek film franchise; and further adaptations in several media.'

starlist = re.findall('\w+ Star Trek \w+',s) #Successfully finds the word before and after

for x in starlist:
    print(x)
```

If I use the code above, I get these results:

by Star Trek legend

the Star Trek adventures

The Star Trek canon

five Star Trek spin

the Star Trek film

However, I want to get the following results:

Star Trek is an American media franchise

created by Star Trek legend Gene Roddenberry

simply called Star Trek

It followed the Star Trek adventures of Captain James T. Kirk (William Shatner)

The Star Trek canon includes The Original Series

five Star Trek spin-off television series

the Star Trek film franchise

Comment: After more study, I realized I could do accomplish my goal much easier using the SpaCy dependency parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boom, ruin my perfect reputation score, please.

```py
import re

s = 'Star Trek is an American media franchise, based on the science fiction television series; created by Star Trek legend Gene Roddenberry. The first television series, simply called Star Trek, and now referred to as "The Original Series", debuted in 1966 and aired for three seasons on NBC. It followed the Star Trek adventures of Captain James T. Kirk (William Shatner), and his crew aboard the starship USS Enterprise, a star exploration vessel built by the United Federation of Planets in the 23rd century. The Star Trek canon includes The Original Series: five Star Trek spin-off television series; an animated series; the Star Trek film franchise; and further adaptations in several media.'

matches = re.findall('[.,]*[\w\s\']*Star Trek[\w\s\'-]*[,.]*',s)

for i,j in enumerate(matches):
    print(i,j)
```

Comment: J.Doe, That gets me close enough! Thank you for the help. I had banged my head on this for a whole day, so you saved me a ton research and study time before I would have figured it out. If you have a little time, I have a couple of questions to help me understand what you did. The first question is, how does it split correctly on the segments with semicolons and colons even though you only have the period and command in the group [.,]? Also, it isn't a problem, but why does it create an index rather than just a list of the text strings?

Comment: Tbh I had to experiment a lot, but the general idea is this:
[TERMINATOR][OTHER WORDS]SEARCH[OTHER WORDS][TERMINATOR].
The tricky part is figuring out what characters need to be included in the classes OTHER WORDS and TERMINATOR and whether their occurences need to be set as optional (*) or obligatory (+). I got the best results with optional, which is why I have all classes starred. With bracket classes, you can create custom classes, so if you need to include both spaces as well as letters in OTHER WORDS, you can just add \s and \w to the brackets. The same logic applies everywhere else.